# What does 不对付 mean?

Tags: word

A sentence from the news reads: 古力娜扎即将代班张雨绮入驻《快乐大本营》，非常有可能在节目中迎来同为新疆娱乐界代表人物的迪力热巴，但令粉丝遗憾的是，据传这两人籍贯背景年龄学历大致相当，彼此却不太对付，此前同框时尚芭莎夜被主持人朱丹搞混名字.

It is a long one with so many interesting points of learning, but now at first I just want to know the meaning of 不对付. What I find from dictionary says 对付 means handle, deal with, but that there should be an object. So in this case, it is a little confusing.

Answer (score 4):

do not like each other

他们互相不喜欢对方

Comment: So can we say 我不对付猪肉 to mean I do not like pork?

Comment: no you can not say that . 不对付only in two same object. you can say the two pig 不对付 means the two pig can not stay together or they will attack.

Comment: @NanningYouth 不对付 is an intransitive phrase. It can't be used the way you put it.

Answer (score 3):

不对付 is a spoken phrase commonly used in northern China (e.g. Dongbei and Beijing).

As other answers stated, 不对付 has the meanings of 合不来 (can't get along with each other) or 不喜欢 (don't like each other).

Just want to state several meanings of 对付 other than "handle" and "deal with":

1. Defeat (击败): 对付敌人 = defeat the enemy (transitive)
2. Make do (将就): 这双旧鞋就对付着穿吧 = just make do with this pair of old shoes (intransitive)
3. Good relationship (合得来): 两人对付/不对付 -- as above (spoken, intransitive)

Answer (score 1):

They didn't deal with each other well, that means their relationship was not good.

Answer (score 1):

Usually used to describe a relationship between two people that is not so good

Answer (score 0):

It's a rarely used saying which means 'have good relationship', 'know each other well'. Don't use it to a Chinese friend or he/she will probably be confused too.

Comment: 有些合不來 or 不太合得來 would be the common expression

Answer (score 0):

她是对付新闻界的一位老手。
She's an old hand at dealing with the press.

对付: cope with, deal with, handle，tackle

据传这两人 ... 彼此却不太对付
It is rumoured that these 2 ... mutually however not very cope with
It is rumoured that these 2 ... don't get along with each other

Comment: Is there any significant semantic difference between 对付 & 应付?

Answer (score -2):

This (不对付) would mean not to deal with; or cannot stand  against.

Comment: Although if it is 不对起，it would mean sorry.